# Webservice not working with script

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Something seems to be wrong with my webservice.

I use the following script:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var name = 'calle';
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'WebService.asmx/GetData',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{'name': '" + name + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Codebehind:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string GetData(string name)
        {
            return name + "add";
        }
```

When I call this script from my codebehind (using webforms) it works fine and returns what it is supposed to, but when I call it from my WebService it does not work, nothing happens. What could be wrong?

My webservice (just in case it's needed):

```
namespace WDBAPP
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
```

Comment: Are you using a POST to "GET" data?

Comment: I am just experimenting with POST since that is what I want to do later with more complicated information posting and getting info from database. But if webservice wont work then I need to fix that first. I just want to know what could be the cause of my webservice not working.

Comment: Why -1? what is wrong with the question?

Comment: You have `dataType: "json"`, but you are returning a simple string, not JSON. Try changing it to `text`.

Comment: Can you tell if that was the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately it was not.

Comment: Is the method on C# being executed? Try a print on `GetData`.

Comment: You need to check on the client side for errors, otherwise we'll just be guessing at what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are posting an string instead of a serialized data.

Try this:

```
data: {name:name},
```